# Single Result from recordset returning w/o being transposed

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I am working on a project where I'm using SQL to return records from a database into a listbox using userinput. Things are fine when there's more than one result, the listbox reads properly. However, when there's only one record, it doesn't transpose it like it does with all the others. [Multiple Returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piSja.png) [Single Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puAZC.png)

I've tried to do an "if employeeoutput.recordcount = 1 then don't transpose" type of thing, but that still sends me with the Single Return.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Stop
'connect to database
'make dynamic code
'profit

'set up DB and Recordset
Dim calldbconn As ADODB.Connection
Dim EmployeeOutput As ADODB.Recordset
Dim EmpData As Variant

'its a special tool we're going to use later
Dim InContactInput As String
Dim FNameInput As String
Dim LNameInput As String
Dim TeamNameInput As String
Dim TeamNumberInput As Integer
Dim SQLString As String

'set it up for a new recordset
Set calldbconn = New ADODB.Connection
Set EmployeeOutput = New ADODB.Recordset

'set the vars
InContactInput = txtInContactNum.Value
FNameInput = txtFirstName.Value
LNameInput = txtLastName.Value
TeamNameInput = cboTeamName.Value
TeamNumberInput = cboTeamName.ListIndex + 1

'---------A bunch of stuff here to build the SQL String----------

'----------------------------------------------------------------

'Time to connect
calldbconn.ConnectionString = StrCallDB
calldbconn.Open

On Error GoTo CloseConnection

With EmployeeOutput
    .ActiveConnection = calldbconn
    .Source = SQLString
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .Open
    EmpData = .GetRows
    On Error GoTo CloseRecordset
End With

'And now, the list box
With lstResults
    .Clear
    .List = Application.Transpose(EmpData)
End With


'close and reset
CloseRecordset:
    EmployeeOutput.Close

CloseConnection:
    calldbconn.Close

Set EmployeeOutput = Nothing
Set calldbconn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You can check, if an array has been returned `isArray(EmpData)` if not omit `Transpose`

Comment: Even when there's no command to transpose it, it still returns the same as the picture :/

Comment: `Application.Transpose` has a habit of making 1D arrays from 2D arrays - you might consider making your own Transpose() function which won't do that.  Eg: use the one from here https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/transpose-array/

Comment: I don't suppose there's an easy way to add a "dummy" record of sorts to a dataset? That would mean that the recordset would never pick up only a singular record